# Добавление using в динамическую компиляцию

Tags: c#, c++, dll, компиляция

Всем доброго времени. Изучая динамическую компиляцию наткнулся на проблему - при добавлении некоторых using в текст кода компилируемой программы, данный код  не компилируется, даже если сами классы из новых using не используются. 
Пример кода который призван компилировать новую программу :

```c++
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Net.Mail;   // intellisense считает ненужной

//-----//

Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}
    };
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);
CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
{ OutputAssembly = "D:\\Proga.EXE", GenerateExecutable = true };
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Net.Mail");
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);
```

вот строка с кодом который компилируется нормально :

```c++
string source =
@" 
using System;
namespace PR
{
    public class Prog
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Send.SayHello();
        }
    }
    public class Send
    {
        public static void SayHello()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Но если мы совсем незначительно изменим программу, например добавим

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

компилятор работать не будет выдав ошибку : Не удалось найти файл метаданных "System.Net.Mail;
"

Вопрос : чего не хватает в исходном коде что бы компилировать проект с using'ами кроме System и содержащий классы из них? И второй вопрос : как подключать DLL из WinApi в программу что бы и они компилировались в новом исполняемом файле ?

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
```

Comment: _компилятор работать не будет._ - намекаешь, что он выдаст какую-то ошибку?

Comment: @Grundy не совсем. Напишет что имя типа или пространства имен 'Net' отсутствует в пространстве имен 'System'

Comment: Хотя согласно https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.mail(v=vs.110).aspx Net находиться именно в System

Comment: Текст ошибки текстом добавь, а не картинкой

Comment: разве картинкой не понятней ?

Comment: Конечно нет. Текст и код должен быть текстом и кодом, а не картинкой. Это позволит облегчить дальнейший поиск по ним, даст возможность скопировать их и поискать отдельно или запустить у себя. В отличие от картинки, которая может весьма плохо выглядеть на разных экранах, тех же мобильных браузеров

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо добавить ссылку на сборку, чтобы ее классы были доступны в коде.

Если вы компилируете код через CodeDOM - то ссылки используемые им сборки задаются через [`CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.referencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("using System.Net.Mail");

Comment: Не удалось найти файл метаданных "using System.Net.Mail"

Comment: @Сергей вы как-то странно сборку обозвали. Обычно в имени сборки нет пробелов...

Comment: я вас не совсем понял ......compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("имя сборки пишется сюда?");

Comment: @Сергей да. Посмотрите имя нужной вам сборки на msdn.

Comment: а разве System.Net.Mail не является именем сборки ?

Comment: @Сергей я не знаю есть ли такая сборка. Имя сборки может не совпадать с именем пространства имен. Но слово "using" частью имени сборки не является точно.

Comment: @Сергей: А вот это лучше подсмотреть в документации. В любом случае слова «using» в имени сборки точно нет.

Comment: Спасибо разобрался. Имя сборки для пространства имен System.Net.Mail это System.dll.  Значит и [DllImport] можно осуществлять так же если добавить в ReferencedAssemblies ссылку на нужный dll ?

Comment: @Сергей нет, там совершенно другой механизм. DllImport отрабатывает во время выполнения, а не во время компиляции; для компилятора это просто атрибут такой.

Comment: @PavelMayorov те добавлять ссылку на сборку через ReferencedAssemblies не нужно, достаточно включить DllImport в код компилируемого приложения ?

Comment: А приложение WinForms компилируется аналогично консольному ?

Comment: @Сергей да, аналогично

Comment: @PavelMayorov  Имя 'InitializeComponent' отсутствует в текущем контексте. Кроме кода Form1.cs  что еще нужно включить в компилируемый код ?

Comment: @Сергей другие файлы с исходным кодом, конечно же.

Comment: @Сергей и хватит уже задавать вопросы, не относящиеся к изначальной теме

Comment: @PavelMayorov Хорошо. Спасибо!)